# Find the user with the highest total score

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find 3 users who has highest total points.

Table: userpoints

```
id  |  userid |  point
----------------------
1      2         5
2      55        5
3      55        10
4      55        10
5      26        5
6      44        20
7      7         30
.
.
.
```

For example for this table i need this result:

userids: [7, 55, 44]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] the question and show it. And explain what the problem with it was.

Comment: `SELECT something, SUM(something_else) total FROM somewhere GROUP BY something ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  userid, sum(point) as points
from teste
group by userid
order by sum(point) desc
Limit 3
```

Example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a11e6a2a3d050cdfa2cac8738123d9e4).

Comment: Oh, I thought it would more to make it a bit more challenging fro the OP, such that they might be induced to expend some actual effort on solving the problem.